# Why was my "not an answer" flag declined on these two "answers"?

Tags: discussion

https://english.stackexchange.com/a/338327/70861 -- Should have been a comment.

https://english.stackexchange.com/a/175655/70861 -- Has nothing at all to do with the question.

Comment: So far, it looks like no-one's flags on those answers have been dealt with at all (far less declined). What evidence do you have that your flags have been declined? Can you add a screenshot from your flags page?

Comment: OK, first time I've ever seen that page.  Missed the fact that I must press the "declined" tab to the right.

Comment: Can you accept your answer to keep the community bot from nudging it back to the top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, when I went to the flags page (first time I'd ever seen it), I saw the "pending" flags and assumed those were the ones being brought to my attention, completely missing the fact that I needed to press the "declined" tab to the right.

I could argue with some of the decisions, but I suspect it would be an uphill battle, so we'll leave it at that.

Comment: Are the two flags marked "helpful"? Those two answers were deleted by voting.